# InflateException error when nesting Fragments within Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, inflate-exception, android-nested-fragment

I have a `Fragment`, which contains two other `Fragment`s, namely a `ListFragment` and a regular `Fragment`. When I inflate the parent `Fragment` I receive an `InflateException` runtime error.

This is due to like #11 in my XML layout code which refers to this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.nanospark.TMS.fragment_profile_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/new_profile_button" />
```

Keep in mind this XML above refers a **nested** `Fragment`.

Is nesting `Fragment`s a supported feature in Android? Are there any alternatives or fixes to this issue?

Logcat:

```
04-17 15:00:58.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 15:00:58.198: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
```

EDIT 1:
From what I've discovered it is supported
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

However I cannot find any good examples of nested Fragments and filling parent fragments with them.

Comment: Have you tried referencing the parent fragment in the XML (Which you should) and then onCreateView() make a transaction to include the nested fragment like shown in the documentation?

Comment: Yes I have. I'm working on it further now and I found an example via GitHub; if I find a solution I will share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it in your fragment code:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, null);

    if (getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("main") == null)
    {
        if (getActivity() == null)
            return null;
        FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        NewsMainFragment nf = (YourNested) YourNestedFragementClass.instantiate(getActivity(), YourNestedFragementClass.class.getName(),savedInstanceState);
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, nf,"main");
        ft.commit();
    }
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: R.id.fragment_container is the id of the placeholder that should contain the nested fragment

Comment: if you add it dynamically like that; should I just use a framelayout in my parent layout to align things correctly?

Comment: You can but it is not necessary

Comment: Would there be another way to assign weights and UI width/height without a framelayout?